# Using simple jQuery in a chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension and I just want to use jquery. So I tried to use it simple to see if it's working or not. I couldn't understand why it's not working.

my `manifest.json`

```
    {
    "name": "otoEA",
    "description": "OTO DERS KATIL",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "icons": {
        "16": "./16x16.png",
        "32": "./32x32.png",
        "48": "./48x48.png",
        "128": "./128x128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "js":        ["./jQuery.min.js", "./oku.js" ],
        "matches":   [ "https://ogr.sakarya.edu.tr/*"],
        "run_at":    "document_end"
    } ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["./jQuery.min.js","./background.js"]
    },
    "options_page": "./options.html",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "https://ogr.sakarya.edu.tr/*",
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "clipboardWrite"
    ]
}
```

and `oku.js`

```
$(function() {
    $("td:contains('2020')").css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: If you want to change the site's appearance, note that it may be a typical modern dynamically constructed site which builds its UI in a script that runs asynchronously after your content script. You can use MutationObserver or setTimeout polling to detect the moment when those elements appear.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yeah, it is. I just used setTimeout and it worked. Thanks!